# HTTP GET Reads wrong values

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I have this object `data`

[image]

I parse the object to use in a HTTP GET

```
baseURL+ "/previewDocument?" + $.param(data)
```

and it generated a url like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/previewDocument?parameters%5BMAIL_BODY%5D=&parameters%5BMAIL_FROM%5D=&parameters%5BMAIL_RECEIVED_DATE%5D=&parameters%5BMAIL_SUBJECT%5D=&parameters%5BMAIL_TO%5D=&deliveryChannel=NONE&templateID=9093
```

My API controller is as such:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/previewDocument", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public byte[] previewDocument(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters, @RequestParam String templateID, @RequestParam String deliveryChannel) {
    // stuff
}
```

The problem is that, instead  of parameters having only the Map related to my `data.parameters`

it has this content:

```
{parameters[MAIL_BODY]=, parameters[MAIL_FROM]=, parameters[MAIL_RECEIVED_DATE]=, parameters[MAIL_SUBJECT]=, parameters[MAIL_TO]=, deliveryChannel=NONE, templateID=9093}
```

Which is wrong. I Should have something like:

```
 {MAIL_BODY=, MAIL_FROM=, MAIL_RECEIVED_DATE=, MAIL_SUBJECT=, MAIL_TO=}
```

This values `(@RequestParam String templateID, @RequestParam String deliveryChannel)` are correctly filled. My only issue is with Map parameters.

Can someone explain me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html):

> If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or
>   `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and a parameter name is not specified,
>   then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names
>   and values.

You can manually remove excess parameters from map or send them as path params.

**Updated:**

Looks like you need to flatten your `data` object first, so you have all the params at the same level. Something like this (I'm not very familiar with JS):

```
function flatten(obj) {
    var result = {};

    function process(element) {
        $.each(element, function(key, value) {
            if (typeof value === 'object') process(value);
            else result[key] = value;
        });
    }
    process(obj);
    return result;
}
```

And then use it to generate URL:

```
baseURL+ "/previewDocument?" + $.param(flatten(data))
```

Comment: but then how can I get the values?